# Cypher query executing stuck without returning resultset in neo4j jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, neo4j, cypher

```
public void updateTopCallers(){
String queryString1 = "MATCH(a:Account) WHERE a.name='" + key + "' MATCH(p:Person)-[:USED_BY]->(a) RETURN p.id as personId LIMIT 1";
try {
    ResultSet resultSet = getQueryResult(queryString1);//in debugging, process didn't continue after this line.
    if (resultSet.next()){
        ownerId = resultSet.getString("personId");
        System.out.println("ownerId:"+ownerId);
        //In here also I'm executing few other cypher queries 
        //using same Neo4jUtil instance.
    }
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

I'm calling updateTopCallers() method inside a thread. Also I'm using large number threads to this task concurrently. As I observed this occurs when I'm using single instance of my Neo4jUtil class (as in Single design pattern).

Here is my Neo4jUtil class.

```
public class Neo4jUtil {
private Neo4jConnection neo4jConnection = null;
private String restUrl = null;
private String driver = null;
private String userName = null;
private String passWord = null;
private static PropertiesUtility propertiesUtility = null;

private Neo4jUtil(){
    try {
        restUrl = getPropertiesCache().getCofigProperty("neo4j_url");
        driver = getPropertiesCache().getCofigProperty("neo4j_driver");
        userName = getPropertiesCache().getCofigProperty("neo4j_user");
        passWord = getPropertiesCache().getCofigProperty("neo4j_pwd");
        createDbConnection();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void createDbConnection(){
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        neo4jConnection = (Neo4jConnection) DriverManager.getConnection(restUrl,userName,passWord);
        System.out.println("neo4jConnection:"+neo4jConnection.toString());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static PropertiesUtility getPropertiesCache() throws Exception {
    if(propertiesUtility==null){
        propertiesUtility = PropertiesUtility.getInstance();
        return propertiesUtility;
    }
    else {
        return propertiesUtility;
    }
}

private static class Neo4jHolder{
    private static final Neo4jUtil NEO4J_INSTANCE = new Neo4jUtil();
}

public static Neo4jUtil getInstance() {
    return Neo4jHolder.NEO4J_INSTANCE;
}

// Querying
public ResultSet getQueryResult(String queryString){
    try{
        Neo4jStatement stmt = (Neo4jStatement) neo4jConnection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(queryString);
        return rs;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

When I'm using following method to get result set for particular cypher it works fine.

```
private ResultSet executeCypher(String queryString){
    try {
        String restUrl = getPropertiesCache().getCofigProperty("neo4j_url");
        String driver = getPropertiesCache().getCofigProperty("neo4j_driver");
        String userName = getPropertiesCache().getCofigProperty("neo4j_user");
        String passWord = getPropertiesCache().getCofigProperty("neo4j_pwd");
        Class.forName(driver);
        Neo4jConnection connection = (Neo4jConnection) DriverManager.getConnection(restUrl, userName, passWord);
        Neo4jStatement stmt = (Neo4jStatement) connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(queryString);
        stmt.close();
        connection.close();
        return rs;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I'm using neo4j-jdbc 2.3.2 as my neo4j java client.

Comment: When I used neo4j-rest-graphdb client it works fine. I had problem with that client when I'm threads.

Comment: what do you mean with "got stuck"

Comment: Can you simplify the code, this code is a mess and it's too hard to reason about for answering this question.

Answer (score 0):

It comes two possibilities to me
First, This

```
final List<String> keyList = keyScanCursor.getKeys();
```

Might return not all keys but some limit. Default neo4j query returns 25 results.

Second
You might have a lot of persons to one key and you lose them limiting return statement.

```
MATCH(person:Person)-[:USED_BY]->(a) RETURN person LIMIT 1"
```

Comment: I'm getting keys from a redis db which contains 15000 keys. Because key is msisdn there should be at least similar number of persons.